# How to manipulate input values javascript? / how to use input data js?

Tags: javascript, function, user-interface

Here is app.js of "countdown" project. It works correctly if I declare:
let newLaunch = "1 July 2023" (by typing inside the app.js).
But when I decided to add UI and allow to input date for visitors it does not work! All  I've achieved is that correct display console.log of input date (when typing to input field of website) but how can I force my code use this input for correct work of app?

It seems easy but I get stuck. Any helps appreciate.

```js
const daysEl = document.getElementById("days")
const hoursEl = document.getElementById("hours")
const minutesEl = document.getElementById("minutes")
const secondsEl = document.getElementById("seconds")

let newLaunch = "1 July 2023" // It works correctly and can be changed

/* It does not work correctly...

let newLaunch = document.querySelector("input");

newLaunch.addEventListener("input", () => {
  
    console.log(newLaunch.value.split("-").reverse().join("-"));

 });
 
*/ 

function countdown () {
    const newLaunchDate = new Date(newLaunch)
    const currentDate = new Date()

    const totalSeconds = (newLaunchDate - currentDate) / 1000
    const days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600 / 24)
    const hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600) % 24
    const minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60) % 60
    const seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds) % 60

    daysEl.innerHTML = days
    hoursEl.innerHTML = formatTime(hours)
    minutesEl.innerHTML = formatTime(minutes)
    secondsEl.innerHTML = formatTime(seconds)

}

const formatTime = time => time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time

//initial call
countdown ()

setInterval(countdown, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's add an input date and work with it. There are many options and some might recommend using library such as "moment.js". But lets keep it simple.

Update: I made some minimal changes so it would work with your example.

```js
const daysEl = document.getElementById("days")
const hoursEl = document.getElementById("hours")
const minutesEl = document.getElementById("minutes")
const secondsEl = document.getElementById("seconds")

var int_id;

const formatTime = time => time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time

function got_date(elem) {

  // the parsed value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd
  var str_date = elem.value + 'T00:00'
  var newLaunch = str_date;
  const newLaunchDate = new Date(newLaunch)

  function countdown() {
    const currentDate = new Date()

    const totalSeconds = (newLaunchDate - currentDate) / 1000
    if (totalSeconds < 0) {
      console.log("target date has passed");
      return;
    }

    const days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600 / 24)
    const hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600) % 24
    const minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60) % 60
    const seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds) % 60

    daysEl.innerHTML = days
    hoursEl.innerHTML = formatTime(hours)
    minutesEl.innerHTML = formatTime(minutes)
    secondsEl.innerHTML = formatTime(seconds)

  }


  //initial call
  countdown()

  clearInterval(int_id);
  int_id = setInterval(countdown, 1000)


}
```

```html
<input id="date" type="date" name="date" oninput="got_date(this)">
<hr>

<span id="days"></span>
<span id="hours"></span>
<span id="minutes"></span>
<span id="seconds"></span>
```

Comment: Perhaps this will be useful to someone... 
The problem in my code was solved by adding value.split("-").reverse().join("/") to have the format mm/dd/yyyy, but not mm-dd-yyyy.
But now I have a different issue: the input format requires: month/day/year to work correctly, but I would like to use: day/month/year when inputting.

Comment: Thank you very much, IT goldman! Even though I almost fixed my own code, your code works as I expected!